# Android Interstitial ad repeating

Tags: android, admob, interstitial

In my app I put Interstitial full page ad. And it is working fine on most phones but when I checked in my friends Galaxy Note 1 the Interstitial ad is repeating and reating. I don't know why it is happening in one mobile phone only.. I checked with more than three other mobile phoe including Samsung Galaxy S2, S3 etc... but in those phones there was no problem and I tested in Emulator also.. there was no problem once i closed the Ad it will not repeat. The problem is with this particular phone , if anybody knows the reason please help... Is this the problem with memory or somethiing ..

I am giving the code below.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.tabpmnth_xm);

        // Create the interstitial.
        interstitial = new InterstitialAd(this);
        interstitial.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxx8x/x2xxxxxxxx");

        // Create ad request.
        AdRequest aadRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
        .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
        .addTestDevice("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
        .build();

        // Begin loading your interstitial.
        interstitial.loadAd(aadRequest);


        interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener(){
              public void onAdLoaded(){
                   displayInterstitial();
              }
    });




public void displayInterstitial() {
        if (interstitial.isLoaded()) {
          interstitial.show();
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry Jocheved for the late replay. If this problem is not happening in every phone it could possibly the problem is in that user's mobile settings. Just check whether in his/her " settings > Developer Options > Do not keep activities " selected or not. If it is selected then the app will destroy every activities as soon as the user left the current activity. So when an interstitial is displayed , the current activity will be normally in onPause. but it will be destroyed and when the user close the interstitial and come back again oncreate will run and the ad will display. To avoid this situation you can inform the user to check whether the option is selected or not.. or otherwise u may need to find some other solution and solve it through programming. thanks..

Answer (score -2):

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/i6zOe2Hy-xc

Check out above link where Google admob engineer has explained why this issue is arising for you. Don't need to include displayInterstitial() inside onAdLoaded(). Either you want to display your interstitial after some time, I use onCountdownTimer() myself to achieve this. For e.g. showing an Ad after 5 seconds.

```
        new CountDownTimer(5000, 5) {
                        @Override
                        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFinish() {
                                 displayInterstitial();
                        }
                    }.start();
```